# How can I write a function which takes another function of a variable and the variable itself as arguments and gives a list of critical points?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, replacement

This is an exercise from Power Programming with Mathematica by Wagner. I need a function which takes a function and a variable as arguments, like this:
critpts[f_,x_]:=

and then on the rhs I've got something like /;Derivative[f[x]]=0 as a condition at the end, and what I want is something that will generate a list of rules like x->0 which describe the values of critical points. An example would be that if the function worked it'd mean something like this: critpts[x^2,x] would generate something like this: x->0. I don't even know how I can generate a list of rules at all.

Comment: Take a look at `Solve`

Comment: Why a capital F in  `.../;Derivative[F[x]]=0`?

Comment: It was a mistake, and should be a lower-case f.

Comment: Maybe you mean `someExpression/;f'[x]==0`, also Equal and not Set

Comment: You should consider giving your function the attribute `HoldAll`.

Comment: Could you pls explain what you mean by critical points?

Comment: Because if you mean points where the derivative is 0, then your condition doesn't make a lot of sense...

Comment: Yeah I mean points where the derivative is zero. I don't know if I should even be using a /; condition test or anything. What should I change about it? Thanks for your help by the way. Or I mean, rather, sorry for my incompetence. I'm new to mathematica and programming in general, just trying to get through the exercises and gain some kind of understanding of how it all works.

Comment: As you can see in the answer below, you shouldn't add this condition. In fact you must not, otherwise your function would only evaluate for constant functions. BTW If you reply comments use something like @TobiasNash, this notifies the corresponding member.

Answer (score 2):

First, how you would you find the critical points of a function, say $f(x)=x^3-x$, from scratch?  I guess you might write

```
D[x^3 - x, x]
(* Out: 3x^2 - 1 *)
```

Then, you want to know when that's equal to zero.  So you might type

```
Solve[% == 0, x]
(* Out: {{x -> -(1/Sqrt[3])}, {x -> 1/Sqrt[3]}} *)
```

where the `%` sign refers to the previous output.

Now at this point, we notice a couple of things.  First, the `Solve` command (which you'll certainly use in your function) returns a list of rules - exactly as you want and said that you weren't certain how to produce.  Second, rather than using `%` to refer to the previous output, you might simply chain the commands into a single command.  So you might have something like

```
Solve[D[x^3 - x, x] == 0, x]
```

Finally, for your program, you probably don't want to be restricted to $x^3-x$, so let's assign a symbol to that - perhaps `f`.

```
f = x^3 - x;
Solve[D[f, x] == 0, x]
```

Well, there's your code - you've just got to use it to define a function.

```
critpts[f_, x_] := Solve[D[f, x] == 0, x];
```

Let's try it

```
critpts[x^3 - x, x]
critpts[Sin[x], x]
critpts[t*Exp[-t^2], t]

(* Out: 
  {{x -> -(1/Sqrt[3])}, {x -> 1/Sqrt[3]}}

  {{x -> ConditionalExpression[-Pi/2 + 2*Pi*C[1], Element[C[1], Integers]]}, 
   {x -> ConditionalExpression[Pi/2 + 2*Pi*C[1], Element[C[1], Integers]]}}

  {{t -> -(1/Sqrt[2])}, {t -> 1/Sqrt[2]}}
*)
```

Naturally, it will inherit many of the restrictions of the `Solve` command.  Thus, the following produces an error and returns an unevaluated `Solve`.

```
In[253]:= critpts[t*Sin[t], t]
(* Out: Solve[t Cos[t] + Sin[t] == 0, t] *)
```

Comment: Maybe you could add why the OP shouldn't use `critpts[f_,x_]/;f'[x]==0` as he was trying to do?